# Initialise CKEDITOR before the element is attached to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, ckeditor

What I want to do is fully initialize the CKEDITOR on a textarea BEFORE the textarea has been attached to the DOM.

I have a function that will clone a html form, attach events and initialise form inputs.

This is so that I can get a fully functioning form through one function call. Making it easy to attain all over the system.

#### HTML

```
<div id="clones" style="display:none">

    <!-- The form to submit Reminders to the system -->
    <form id="reminder-submit-form">
        <input type="text" name="date" />
        <textarea name="note"></textarea>
        <input type="button" class="submit" value="Add Reminder"/>
    </form>

</div>
```

#### JS

```
function getReminderForm()
{
    var form = $('#reminder-submit-form').clone();

    form.find('[name="date"]').datepicker();

    // These are what I tried...
    // CKEDITOR.replace('note')                      // FAILS
    // CKEDITOR.replace(form.find('[name="note"]')); // FAILS
    // form.find('[name="note"]').ckeditor()         // FAILS

    form.find('input.submit').on('click', function(){
        // handle click
    });
    return form;
}
```

Because of this design... I can use the form in many places like so:

```
var popup_content = $('<div/>')
                        .append('<h1>Add a Reminder</h1>')
                        .append(getReminderForm());
$.fancybox(popup_content);
```

The problem is, the call to:

```
CKEDITOR.replace
```

will not work, because CKEDITOR searches the DOM for the element. However my element is not yet attached the the DOM.

Can anybody think of a work around? Because if I cannot then all over my system ill have code like this:

```
// attach form to container
$('#some-container').append(getReminderForm());

// Initialize AFTER form has been attached
CKEDITOR.replace('note');
```

When i could just have:

```
$('#some-container').append(getReminderForm());
```

Comment: Or, you could abstract that behind a function. `$.fn.placeReminderForm = function(){this.append(getReminderForm());CKEDITOR.replace('note');};` then just do `$('#some-container').placeReminderForm()`

Comment: I could yes, Thanks for your comment. I'll probably end up using this, but I am still interested if it is possible to bind CKEDITOR before the element is attached. Ideally I'd want to bind ckeditor INSIDE the getReminderForm function BECAUSE thats where the rest of the stuff is bound, and it kind makes sense :)

Comment: I agree, that's why i posted it as a comment rather than an answer. It's a solution, but not quite the best way of doing it.

Comment: I have something you can try. Use http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-appendTo Basically, you would select the h1 and use it as `element`.

Comment: I couldnt get `appendTo` to work... I think it is identical to replace, expect it puts the editor INSIDE the element you select. It is still limited to attached DOM elements only :(

Comment: No, `element` can be a dom node, an id string, or name string. pass the dom node to it.

Comment: `CKEDITOR.appendTo(popup_content.find("h1").get(0))` for example. Instead of the h1, you would target whatever you want the editor to be appended to.

Comment: Or, maybe use .replace and use the same concept, target the textarea within popup_content. `CKEDITOR.replace(popup_content.find("#thetextarea").get(0))`

Comment: I've tried them... The issue still remains that the element you select must be attached to the DOM :/

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor **must** be created with an existing DOM element (`CKEDITOR.replace`) or existing parent (`CKEDITOR.appendTo`).

If I were you, I'd simply create a function:

```
function appendReminderForm( where ) {
    // Clone existing form...
    // ...

    // Append cloned form to DOM.
    where.append( clonedForm );

    // Replace textarea to create the editor.
    CKEDITOR.replace( clonedTextarea );
}
```

Note that when calling `CKEDITOR.replace`, an argument passed to the function must be a **unique** identifier, so `CKEDITOR.replace( 'note' )` doesn't make much sense because there are two elements of the same `name` (clones). It's better to retrieve a native DOM element (`textarea` of cloned form), and pass it to `CKEDITOR.replace`.